Align the time range across two or more separate time series
I have several time series that fall within the same time range, but with different sampling rates. The start and end times are the same for all series.
series_a_times = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-08']
series_b_times = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-08']
series_c_times = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-08']

Is there a package that can standardize the sampling rate across these time series and apply interpolation where needed? The desired sampling times are:
series_times = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-08']


not sure of any specific modules - possibly in pandas ? ...
but a date range manipulation may be all that's required , example below
(i'd change your series_x_times to series_x_dates as they're dates not times)
import datetime

series_a_times = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-08']
series_b_times = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-08']
series_c_times = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-08']

fromDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(min(series_a_times+series_b_times+series_c_times),"%Y-%m-%d")
toDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(max(series_a_times+series_b_times+series_c_times),"%Y-%m-%d")

newSeries = [str(date.date()) for date in (fromDate + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range((toDate - fromDate).days + 1))]

print( f'new:{newSeries}' )

